# AndEngine swf animation or swf to SVG spritesheet

Tags: android, flash, animation, svg, andengine

In the AndEngineSVGTextureRegionExtension there is a way to use SVG spritesheet with the function called createTiledFromAsset to perform animation. If I create the svg spritesheet manually, the animation doesn't go smooth in slow cases or I have have to manually create lots of frames which is very painful. In flash, we can perform smooth animation. So, is there a way so that I can use the smoothly animated swf file into AndEngine or convert the swf to SVG spritesheet directly? Or is it possible to do this with actionscripting!

Comment: what about swf to bitmap texture, would that be acceptable?

Comment: No, I need SVG so that I can use one resource to support all screen sizes.

Comment: have you considered just using flash? AIR for android and AIR for iOS work pretty good these days. Then there are tools for converting vectors to bitmap textures.

Comment: I am just working with AndEngine. And I am more concern on making SVG spritesheet from swf or fla. I have to use SVG because I am embedding SVG inside code. But for PNG or other images, I have to find another way to embed pictures inside the code which will be more painful to me. Also pictures will not look good in every screen sizes.